# Referencing matrix elements for a list of row.names and colnames

Tags: r, matrix, dplyr, vectorization, apply

I have a `data.frame`, consisting of two columns, which correspond to `row.names` and `colnames` of a numeric matrix. For example:

```
myDF <- data.frame(curr1 = sample(row.names(euro.cross), 5), 
                   curr2 = sample(colnames(euro.cross), 5))
```

I'm trying to return a vector, the same length as `nrow(myDF)`, which contains the elements of `euro.cross` corresponding with the values in `myDF$curr1` and `myDF$curr2`. This is trivial for one element. For example, the first row in `myDF` corresponds with the value `euro.cross[myDF$curr1[1], myDF$curr2[1]]`. However, when I pass vectors to the square brackets, a matrix is returned (i.e., `euro.cross[myDF$curr1, myDF$curr2]` returns a matrix, instead of a vector of `length(myDF$curr1)`).

How do I vectorize this operation such that I can do something like:

```
myDF$rate <- euro.cross[myDF$curr1, myDF$curr2]
```

Obviously, I could perform a loop, but I'm looking for a more elegant way to code it. Haven't had success utilizing *apply* functions thus far.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert `myDF` into a matrix, and directly use it to extract elements from `euro.cross`, which triggers *Indexing via a character matrix* (more detail see `?'['` ***Matrices and arrays*** section) and does what you need:

```
euro.cross[as.matrix(myDF)]
# [1]  1.204921087 18.305448539  0.003070713  0.010992059  0.057234508
```